# Meaning of (#) in Sum of # in Einstein Analytics

Tags: einstein-analytics

In Einstein analytics I could find something called as # on which we can perform sum, min, max and average. However I couldn't understand on what field this action is performed!! Can someone explain me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For people who are doing trailhead on Einstein Analytics desktop exploration and using DTC Opportunity dataset which is given by salesforce. # is a column which represents the quantity of products sold. Coincidentally they have given the data serially starting from  1 to 671.

Answer (score 0):

Since the latest release of Einstein Analytics Spring '20 in that window you see the label on the left and the technical name on the right.
So # really is the columns Label, while Column1 is the technical name you would use in SAQL or the dashboards JSON.